# DirectFB applications refuse to start

Tags: linux

I get something like:

```
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.2.10 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (c) 2001-2008  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
        (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
      ----------------------------------------------------------------

(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2010-06-30 18:13) 
(*) Direct/Memcpy: Using Generic 64bit memcpy()
(!) Direct/Util: opening '/dev/fb0' and '/dev/fb/0' failed
    --> No such file or directory
(!) DirectFB/FBDev: Error opening framebuffer device!
(!) DirectFB/FBDev: Use 'fbdev' option or set FRAMEBUFFER environment variable.
(!) DirectFB/Core: Could not initialize 'system_core' core!
    --> Initialization error!
Could not initialize graphics driver directfb:
Initialization error!
```

when I launch (i.e.):

```
$ links2 -driver directfb
```

Any ideas?

*It's a brand new thing for me, maybe I'm misunderstanding some basic concepts.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the appropriate frame buffer module for your video card first.

Comment: Can you be more specific (examples, howtos)? I've got an ATI video card.

Comment: `modprobe radeonfb`

Comment: Tried that, same issue. The device `/dev/fb0` still doesn't exist.